# Android ImageButton with gradient AND transparent image background[Image included]

Tags: android, transparency, gradient, imagebutton

Id like to achieve the effect seen in the image ive provided below.....possible?

I know how to do a gradient and I know how to set a imagebuttons src/bg to a drawable but i have nooooooo idea where to even start with pulling off both at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Don't see an image...

Answer (score 2):

It's actually incredibly simple. To avoid overdraw by layering a bunch of views, just add a `ColorFilter` to your `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#994dace3"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

No added overdraw, and you can set whatever color you want, and experiment with different PorterDuff blending modes.

Example:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Hi, could you explain this: `To avoid overdraw by layering a bunch of views, just add a ColorFilter to your ImageView`? What `bunch of views` are you referring to? Are you saying that setting `src` and applying `ColorFilter` to an ImageView yields better performance compared to setting `src` and `background` attributes on an ImageView?

Comment: That is correct. Done that way, the background will first be drawn, then the source will be drawn over that. This results in a single draw, the colors are just modified before being drawn.

Comment: From digging through the source code: Setting ImageView's `src="@color/___"` creates a `ColorDrawable`. A ColorDrawable fills the canvas with a given color (as opposed to drawing it), thus making it less resource/system-intensive. All is good but this still does not trump: `results in a single draw`. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Filling the canvas implies a draw. Drawables are drawn.

Comment: @kcoppock can we add gradient using any filter over an image?

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to do a gradient and I know how to set a imagebuttons
>   src/bg to a drawable but i have nooooooo idea where to even start with
>   pulling off both at the same time

I think what you are referring to as being a `gradient` is actually a color with transparency value set. From what I can tell, you are looking for something like this:

[image]

You can achieve this using the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/the_picture"
        android:src="@color/transparent_color" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Message!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` is used to position the `TextView` over the `ImageButton`. The `Picture` is set as the background. The `src` is set to a color(any color) with a transparency value between `00`(completely transparent) and `ff` (completely opaque). In the image above, I have used a transparency of `70`. So, say you pick Green(#00ff00), add transparent value to it: #7000ff00 and add it to `res/values/colors.xml`. You can also use it directly as I have done below.

Here's the complete xml code for the activity in the pic above:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/original" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/original"
                android:src="#7000ff00" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Optional Message!"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can set a custom font to the TextView(as in the picture you've provided) in code.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i was truly refering to a gradient , but i might be able to settle on your solution. I will give it a try and accept the answer if it works out .